# Getting an error trying to insert field in a Word table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, form-fields, word-table

I create a formfield (textinput), and when I go to name it I get:
**91
Object variable or With block variable not set**

There are dozens of other places in this macro where I do the same exact thing and it works fine.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub IRPMs()
Dim objCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim tmpField As FormField
Dim strOut As String

Set doc = ActiveDocument
i = 0
j = 1
k = 0

Call grabInfo

strFieldName(1) = "Property:  "
strFieldName(2) = "General Liability:  "
strFieldName(3) = "Auto Liability:  "
strFieldName(4) = "Auto Phys Dam:  "
strFieldName(5) = "Inland Marine:  "

'' Remove document protection, if necessary
If doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then doc.Unprotect

On Error GoTo IRPMerror

doc.Tables(3).Rows(9).Cells(2).Select
Selection.Delete
doc.Tables(3).Rows(10).Cells(2).Select
Selection.Delete

strSQL = "redacted"

objCon.Open "redacted"

rs.Open strSQL, objCon

If Not rs.EOF Then
    For k = 0 To 4
        If rs(k) <> "" Then i = i + 1
    Next

    doc.Tables(3).Rows(9).Cells(2).Select

    If i = 0 Then
        Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine

        Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
        tmpField.Name = "irpms1"
    Else
        For k = 0 To 4
            If rs(k) <> "" Then
                Selection.InsertAfter (strFieldName(j))
                Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine

                Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
                tmpField.Name = "irpms" & j

                If j <= i And j < 5 Then
                    Selection.InsertAfter Chr(11)
                End If

                strOut = rs(k)
                If Left(strOut, 1) = "." Then strOut = "0" & strOut

                doc.FormFields("irpms" & j).Result = strOut
            End If

            j = j + 1
        Next
    End If
Else
    Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine

    Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
    tmpField.Name = "irpms1"
End If

rs.Close

strSQL = "redacted"

'rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient        ' I've tried with and without setting the cursor
rs.Open strSQL, objCon, adOpenDynamic

MsgBox (rs.RecordCount)
i = rs.RecordCount

If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    doc.Tables(3).Rows(10).Cells(2).Select

    Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
    tmpField.Name = "Ducks"         ' This is merely for testing; throws the error

    If i = 1 Then
        Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine

        Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
        tmpField.Name = "devi1"
    Else
        For k = 1 To i
            Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
            tmpField.Name = "devi" & k

            'doc.FormFields("devi" & k).Result = rs(0) & " Deviations: " & rs(1)

            If k <> rs.RecordCount Then
                Selection.InsertAfter (Chr(11))
            End If

            rs.MoveNext
        Next
    End If
End If

GoTo IRPMexiter

IRPMerror:
MsgBox ("IRPM" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
GoTo IRPMexiter

IRPMexiter:
If Not rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = Nothing
If rs.State Then rs.Close
If Not objCon Is Nothing Then Set objCon = Nothing
If objCon.State Then objCon.Close

If doc.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then doc.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, noreset:=True, Password:=""

If Err Then End

Exit Sub
```

SQL and connection parameters have been redacted, they don't seem to have any issues.  "grabInfo" retrieves data from the document properties to pass into the SQL.  "doc" is declared publicly elsewhere.

So, it runs through the first part fine, and has for over a month now.  After the rs is closed and reopened, it doesn't like me using "tmpfield" anymore.

I appreciate any advice.  First post, so please let me know if I can improve my question or if I broke any rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are situations when Word is not able to insert something because the current selection does not support that kind of object. If it's tried in the Word interface, as a user, an error message will appear to that effect... Or Word will simply do a "best guess" and create the object in the nearest valid position.

The object model (VBA) isn't always so forgiving and will simply refuse, often with a not so informative error message.

In this case, an entire table cell is selected and Word is unable to create a form field within the cell structures (as opposed to within the text area of the cell). Reducing the selection to a single point (blinking insertion point / cursor) will allow creating the form field. The `Collapse` method can do this, as the following code sample demonstrates:

```
doc.Tables(3).Rows(10).Cells(2).Select
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart 
Set tmpField = Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
tmpField.Name = "Ducks"
```