# Word- VBA- How To Insert Macro Button Form Field Into Table Cell?

Tags: vba, ms-word, insert, form-fields, word-table

I am trying to insert a macro button form field into cell 2 but I keep getting `Run-Time Error '4605': This method or property is not available because the drawing operation cannot be applied to the current selection`.

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oForm As Fields

Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range)
    
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(2)
    Set oForm = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(oCell.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "MACROBUTTON  test1 - ", PreserveFormatting:=False)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```

Debugger highlights the following:

```
Set oForm = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(oCell.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "MACROBUTTON  test1 - ", PreserveFormatting:=False)
```

Which was adapted from the recorded macro below which successfully inserts a form field by manually selecting the desired cell and running the macro

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "MACROBUTTON  test1 - ", PreserveFormatting:=False
```

I was looking at [Getting an error trying to insert field in a Word table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010165/getting-an-error-trying-to-insert-field-in-a-word-table-cell) but couldn't figure out how to adapt to my code.

Comment: Try change the oForm declaration to the singular:

Comment: Negative.  Still get the same error :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems.
You've declared oForm as Fields, it should be **Field**. You're inserting a single field, not a collection.
You can't insert a field into the cell range, you first have to collapse the range to a single insertion point.

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oForm As Field
Dim oRange as Range

Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range)
    
    Set oRange = oNewRow.Cells(2).Range
    oRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Set oForm = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(oRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "MACROBUTTON  test1 - ", PreserveFormatting:=False)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!